# prototypal inheritance & how to do a super()

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm trying to understand how to create inheritance. I think I have it (below), but the part I can't figure out is how to call the "baseclass" method (ie, doing a "super()"). How do I call the delegate's talk() method below?

(demo link: https://plnkr.co/edit/H76NFBiuWqgaZaUfR7H2?p=preview)

```
function Person(name) {
  var api = {
    name,
    talk
  }
  return api;

  function init(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  function talk() {
    return (`I am ${this.name}`)
  }
}


function Student(name, major) {

  var api = {
    major: major,
    talk
  };
  var o = $.extend({}, Person(name), api);
  return o;

  function changeMajor(newMajor) {
    this.major = newMajor;

  }

  function talk() {
    var str = ""
    // var str = Person.prototype.talk.call(this)
    str += ` and I study ${major}`;
    return str;
  }


}

var s = Student("Sue", "Economics")
console.log(s.talk())
```

Comment: If you use `$.extend`-based inheritance, you don't need `Object.create` at all.

Comment: Thanks. That part has now been corrected. I eliminated the Object.create, but I don't see how it's possible to emulate method.super() ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lose the reference to the "super" *talk* method from the `Person` object when using `extend`:

```
var o = $.extend({}, Person(name), api);
```

Although that parent object is created, it is not stored. Only the modified version of it (with `api.talk` overriding its *talk* method) is available in *o*.

So... you need to keep a reference to the original *talk* method:

```
var proto = Person(name);
var o = $.extend({}, proto, api);
```

And then reference it:

```
var str = proto.talk.call(this);
```

Note that since ES6 you can use the native `Object.assign` which has similar functionality as `$.extend`.

```js
function Person(name) {
  var api = {
    name,
    talk
  };
  return api;

  function init(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  function talk() {
    return (`I am ${this.name}`)
  }
}


function Student(name, major) {
  var api = {
    major: major,
    talk
  };
  var proto = Person(name);
  var o = Object.assign({}, proto, api);
  return o;

  function changeMajor(newMajor) {
    this.major = newMajor;
  }

  function talk() {
    var str = proto.talk.call(this);
    str += ` and I study ${major}`;
    return str;
  }
}

var s = Student("Sue", "Economics");
console.log(s.talk());
```

Comment: `Object.assign` is available as of ES6, IE8 even in standards mode will catch fire 8-)

Comment: Another issue with `Object.assign`: jQuery's `$.extend` allows for recursive merging [via first argument = true](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/), the former doesn't support that

Comment: Corrected to *"ES6"*. I used the word *similar* on purpose ;-) For this case, it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could reveal the `init` method in your `api` objects but mark it as `I'm not part of the published API, I only happen to be public here` so to say. Leveraging a naming convention you could do something like this:

```
function Person(name) {
    var api = {
        "__init__": function () {
            // I'm part of the API but please treat me as private
        },
        talk: function () {
            // Do sth.
        }
    };
    return api;
}

function Student(name, major) {
    var personApi = Person(name);
    var api = {
        "__init__": function () {
            // I'm also part of the API but treat me as private
            personApi.__init__.call(this, name)
        },
        talk: function () {
            return personApi.talk.call(this);
        }
    };
    return api;
}
```

But then you'd have to marshall around the `this` and you have to think about not accidentally overriding you `__init__` so you customize your own `$.extend()` function... the rabbit hole goes deep :-). Things like this have been done by some frameworks in the past but I personally wouldn't recommend rolling your own object system - it's fun as a toy but in this day and age there are better options.

The *old* ES5 way to do this is via constructor functions:

```
// Base `class` is just a constructor function
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.talk = function () {
    // Do sth.
};

function Student(name, major) {
    Person.call(this, name); // emulating super(name)
}
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Student.prototype.changeMajor = function () {
    // Do sth.
};

// later
var homer = new Student("Homer Simpson", "Donuts");
```

In modern browsers or with the help of a transpiler say [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/) or [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) you can do this - which is probably what you wanted in the first place:

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    talk() {
        // Do sth.
    }
}

class Student extends Person {
    constructor(name, major) {
        super(name); // proper super(name);
        this.major = major; // Or anything you want to do
    }

    changeMajor() {
        // Do sth.
        super.talk();
    }
}

// later
let homer = new Student("Homer Simpson", "Donuts");
```